# Element is not clickable in chrome

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, watir

I'm unable to click/select an option from the drop down, when I used .send_keys('\n') to simulate the click in chrome and works(Expands the drop down) but, unable to select the option.

The solution suggested by @PeterBernier works well in the case where the element is wrapped in a div or a span.@PeterBernier, could you please suggest how to select option from the expanded drop down.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cW411.png)

Comment: Post the sample HTML please.

Comment: @Rajagopalan, added html image

Comment: First you click that drop down and then locate that option and issue the click. From your given HTML I can't know which one is drop down and which one is option.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this xpath below:

```
"//div[@id='oj-listbox-drop']/ul/li/div"
```

Comment: I'm using same xpath but no use